# lxml - how to remove element but not it's content?

Tags: python, lxml

Let's assume I have following code:

```
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
    <a></a>
    <ul>...</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my code:

```
div_parents = root_element.xpath('//div[div]')

for div in reversed(div_parents): 
    if len(div.getchildren()) == 1:
        # remove second div and replace it with it's content
```

I'm reaching div's with div children and then I want to remove the child div if that's the only child it's parent has. The result should be:

```
<div id="first">
   <a></a>
   <ul>...</ul>
</div>
```

I wanted to do it with:

```
div.replace(div.getchildren()[0], div.getchildren()[0].getchildren())
```

but unfortunatelly, both arguments on replace should consist of only one [element](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html). Is there something easier than reassigning all properties of first div to second div and then replacing both? - because I could do it easily with:

```
div.getparent().replace(div, div.getchildren()[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `copy.deepcopy` as [suggested in the docs](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-are-lists):

For example:

```
div_parents = root_element.xpath('//div[div]')

for outer_div in div_parents:
    if len(outer_div.getchildren()) == 1:
        inner_div = outer_div[0]
        # Copy the children of innder_div to outer_div
        for e in inner_div: outer_div.append( copy.deepcopy(e) )
        # Remove inner_div from outer_div
        outer_div.remove(inner_div)
```

Full code used to test:

```
import copy
import lxml.etree

def pprint(e): print(lxml.etree.tostring(e, pretty_print=True))

xml = '''
<body>
    <div id="first">
      <div id="second">
        <a>...</a>
        <ul>...</ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
'''

root_element = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
div_parents = root_element.xpath('//div[div]')

for outer_div in div_parents:
    if len(outer_div.getchildren()) == 1:
        inner_div = outer_div[0]
        # Copy the children of innder_div to outer_div
        for e in inner_div: outer_div.append( copy.deepcopy(e) )
        # Remove inner_div from outer_div
        outer_div.remove(inner_div)

pprint(root_element)
```

Output:

```
<body>
    <div id="first">
      <a>...</a>
        <ul>...</ul>
      </div>
</body>
```

Note: The enclosing `<body>` tag in the test code is unnecessary, I was just using it for testing multiple cases.  The test code operates without issue on your input.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use list-replacement:

```
 from lxml.etree import fromstring, tostring

 xml = """<div id="first">
   <div id="second">
     <a></a>
     <ul>...</ul>
   </div>
 </div>"""


 doc = fromstring(xml)
 outer_divs = doc.xpath("//div[div]")

 for outer in outer_divs:
     outer[:] = list(outer[0])


 print tostring(doc)
```